# M/H2/1 Queue - Explicit Expression for Response Time Distribution

Tags: queueing-theory

I am looking for a reference to an *explicit* expression to the $M/H_2/1$ queue's response time distribution. I.e., when you invert the PK-Formula, I am looking for a reference that gives a "nice" expression for the response time distribution.

Thanks for help in these matters.

Comment: What do you mean by H2? The hypoexponential distribution with two phases? Have you computed the result you wish to find the inverse of? Some inverse transforms can be computed analytically using Mathematica or Wolfram|Alpha (e.g. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseLaplaceTransform%5B1%2F%281+%2B+s%29%2C+s%2C+t%5D)

Comment: Yes, this is the $Hyperexponential-2$ distribution. I've tried to invert it using Mathematica, and the inverse transform is crazy long. So, I know it can be inverted, the question is that I know this research has been done and am looking for a "simple" and "nice" expression for the Laplace transform. I just can't find it in any of the texts that I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a first come first served service discipline, using parameters $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ for the two phases of the hyperexponential distribution and $p$ for the routing probability between these two phases and $\lambda$ for the arrival rate to the queue, I compute $F(t)$, the response time distribution, to be

$$ \frac{(\mu_1 \mu_2+\lambda  \mu_1 (p-1)-\lambda \mu_2 p) e^{\frac{1}{2} t (\lambda -\mu_1-\mu_2)}}{\mu_1 \mu_2 \sqrt{R}} \left(\sinh \left(\frac{\sqrt{R} t}{2}\right) (\mu_2 (\lambda +\mu_1-\mu_2)+p (\mu_1-\mu_2) (\lambda -\mu_1-\mu_2))+\sqrt{R} (\mu_2+p (\mu_1-\mu_2)) \cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{R} t}{2}\right)\right)$$

where $R=\lambda ^2+(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2-2 \lambda  (2 p-1) (\mu_1-\mu_2)$ as the inverse and can't see a way to significantly simplify the expression.

See a screenshot of the Mathematica calculation below. (Please excuse typos in the first couple of lines which should obviously read 'transform of service time distribution' and 'mean service time', and not mention waiting times.
[image: Mathematica code for evaluation of response time inversion]

Comment: Thanks - I got a similar result in Mathematica as well. I guess this is a "simplified" as it can get for now.